# Symfony2, is there any similar way to work like with SpringMVC interceptors?

Tags: symfony

currently I'm working with Symfony2 and it is an awesome framework.

I worked with SpringMVC and it has the concept of "interceptor" which catches requests to any "controller" and allows to make, for example, checks too know if user is logged.

Is there any annotation of router way to do something similar with Symfony2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach event listeners to respond to a framework event. Take a look at:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

There are a number of events you can subscribe to, all of them available on the docs:

http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelEvents.html

Probably you are looking for the REQUEST event, it should look something like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class Listener
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $router;
    private $service_container;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Routing\Router $router, $service_container) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->service_container = $service_container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
         // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

And on services.xml:

```
<service id="max4.sms.listener"  class="Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\Logger">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" />
        <argument type="service" id="router" />
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>
```

You define the event you are listening to with

```
<tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" />
```

And the arguments injected into the **__construct()** method (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) with:

```
<argument type="service" id="router" />
<argument type="service" id="service_container" />
```